# How write a file in CodenadeOne

Tags: codenameone

I am trying to write a file in CodenameOne - My end goal is to have the csv file. I would like to know how to write a simple text file then I will tweak my code to format it as CSV. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Codename One has `Storage` and `FileSystemStorage` each of which has its trade offs see https://www.codenameone.com/manual/files-storage-networking.html

E.g to use `Storage` use:

```
try(OutputStream os = Storage.getInstance().createOutputStream(filename")) {
   os.write(text);
} catch(IOException err) {
   Log.e(err);
}
```

Comment: I find out that doing it that way lead to permission issues when trying to use that file outside of my application. When creating the file with storage it is located in my application storage folder and may be access only my app. Instead of Storage I had to use FileSystemStorage with a path to a folder that is not restricted.

Comment: You need to use `FileSystemStorage` but check the root type dynamically. You hardcoded a path in your solution which will not work when you go to other devices. Notice that this usage won't work for you on other devices and is completely Android specific as apps don't have access to the files of other apps

Answer (score 0):

Here how I made it work - please let me know if it can be optimized in any way. The class Record is just a wrapper for the information that forms an entry line.

```
try{

    String path = "/storage/sdcard0/my_csv_file.csv";
    OutputStream os = FileSystemStorage.getInstance().openOutputStream(path);

    DataOutputStream dos = new DataOutputStream(os);

    String headers = "ID,DATE,CENTRE_COMMERCIAL,CATEGORIE,"
                            + "PRODUIT,MARQUE,PRIX_MONTANT,PRIX_MONNAIE,UNITE_MESURE,"
                            + "PRECISION,ORIGINE\n";
                    dos.writeChars(s);
                    for(Record record : Record.savedRecords()){
                        dos.writeChars(record.csvFormat());
                    }
                    dos.flush();
                    dos.close();
                }
catch(Exception e){
    e.printStackTrace();
     }
```